# IF Statement for Date comparison

Tags: excel

I am currently creating a system where we tag the response time as "breached" or "within Service Level". We receive issues that needs to be addressed within 15 minutes. So, for example, we receive an issue at 12/2/2015 10:20:25 AM (that is by the way the format for the date on the excel), and it needs to be responded before 12/2/2015 10:35:25 AM or it will be tagged as "breached". In this case, as soon as the issue is posted, it should automatically create a response time that is 15 minutes from the time received and should compare the time if it is within 15 minutes or more for the tagging. Is there anything that can help create an IF statement that will tag the response as "breached" or "within Service Level" depending if it is within the 15-minute-mark as soon as it is received?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see it happening in a couple of ways.  I will assume three columns.  Column A time received, Column B Service Limit (+15 min) and Column C Alert

Lets say a received call time is logged in A2 as 2016/04/19 00:50.  In column B you place to following formula to add 15 minutes:

```
=A2+TIME(0,15,0)
```

To get a real time text alert to the status, in column C use the following

```
=IF(NOW()<B2,"Within Service Level","Breached")
or
=IF(NOW()<=B2,"Within Service Level","Breached")
```

[image: Results]

Comment: there is a chance that the now() is only calculated when a cell value is changed.  Meaning if you get a call E will log as within service, but if you stare at the screen for 16 minutes without doing anything it may not change.

Comment: After staring at my screen, it does indeed not recheck. if nothing changes on the spreadsheet but it will refresh and check its self every time a cell is changed and the sheet performs a calculation.  Dont have to much to worry about if you are getting regular entries, and do not have the sheet set to manual calculations I would think.